# Cannot partially deserialize JSON into Immutables object with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, immutables-library

I have a JSON file that I read via `restTemplate` and want to store only certain fields in to my object. The call is successfull but my object does not contain the informations from the JSON. [This](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Gregsen/936f0dc5f1a83687ada6b64a0fe20a0c/raw/1ee44d3e7aa94851a811108b2606e803f8734c8d/example.json) is the file and I am only interested in the `my-channels` object.

my pom.xml:

```
<!-- SNIP standard stuff generated by start.spring.io -->
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
            <artifactId>value</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

my JacksonConfig that disables failing on missing fields and has kebab-case enabled:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());

        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.KEBAB_CASE);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

The object to hold my data.

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = com.example.demo.ImmutableGist.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = com.example.demo.ImmutableGist.class)
public interface AbstractGist {
    List<ImmutableMyChannels> myChannels();

    @Value.Immutable
    @JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableMyChannels.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableMyChannels.class)
    interface AbstractMyChannels {
        String channelId();

        String locale();
    }
}
```

and my main with the commandlinerunner:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    private static final String URL = "https://rawgit.com/Gregsen/936f0dc5f1a83687ada6b64a0fe20a0c/raw/1ee44d3e7aa94851a811108b2606e803f8734c8d/example.json";
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return args -> {
            ImmutableGist gist = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, ImmutableGist.class);

            log.info(gist.toString());
        };
    }
}
```

The application compiles and runs, the output, however, is simply `Gist{salesChannels=[]}` (minus the whole spring default output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after some more fiddling around and reading, it seems, the issue can be resolved as such:

instead of using `@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableMyChannels.class)` one should use the builder, that is also generated.

`@JsonDeserialize(builder = ImmutableMyChannels.Builder.class)`.